# How to Utilize Intel AMX or DSA Instructions in JavaScript or WebAssembly for High-Performance Computing Tasks?

Tags: javascript, performance, webassembly

##### Background:

I am working on a high-performance computing project that requires intensive matrix computations and data streaming operations. Given the potential performance benefits, I am interested in leveraging Intel's Advanced Matrix Extensions (AMX) and Data Streaming Accelerator (DSA) instructions. My application is developed with a web-based interface, and the core computational work is implemented in JavaScript and WebAssembly. I aim to enhance my application's performance by directly utilizing these hardware acceleration features.

##### Objective:

My goal is to understand how I can directly call or otherwise utilize Intel AMX and DSA instructions within my JavaScript code or from within a WebAssembly module. Specifically, I'm looking for ways to integrate these instructions to accelerate matrix multiplication operations and optimize data streaming processes in my web application.

##### What I Have Tried:

1. Research on existing JavaScript APIs or WebAssembly extensions that may support direct interaction with hardware acceleration features, but found limited resources.
2. Exploration of Emscripten and WebAssembly System Interface (WASI) documentation for any hints on accessing CPU-specific instructions or features, without success.
3. Preliminary experiments with WebAssembly modules written in C/C++, attempting to inline assembly with AMX and DSA instructions, but facing challenges in integration and performance measurement.

##### Challenges:

- Lack of clear documentation or examples on integrating Intel-specific instructions like AMX or DSA within a web application context.
- Uncertainty about the feasibility of accessing such low-level hardware features from high-level languages like JavaScript or through WebAssembly.
- Difficulty in measuring the performance impact or verifying the correct use of these instructions in a web environment.

##### Questions:

1. Has anyone successfully integrated Intel AMX or DSA instructions in a web application using JavaScript or WebAssembly? If so, could you share your approach and any sample code?
2. Are there specific tools, libraries, or methodologies recommended for accessing and utilizing these CPU instructions effectively in a web context?
3. What are the best practices for ensuring compatibility and maximizing performance when attempting to leverage such hardware-specific features in web applications?

##### Additional Context:

- I am specifically targeting modern Intel processors equipped with AMX and DSA capabilities.
- My web application is computationally intensive and would greatly benefit from any performance optimizations these technologies can offer.
- I understand the challenges of working at such a low level in a web environment but am hopeful there are solutions or workarounds.

Comment: This post has a number of issues, including asking multiple questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question and soliciting best practices. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic and soliciting recommendations for tooling https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource

Answer (score 1):

WebAssembly does not support instructions that would map well into AMX or DSA yet. You can probably get a sense of the level of support for SIMD instructions on this [empscripten documentation page](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/simd.html).

New WASM/SIMD instructions typically get proposed in [this issue tracker](https://github.com/WebAssembly/simd/issues). There are not many users on the Web with AMX/DSA instructions, so it is unlikely that their addition to the WebAssembly spec would be prioritized.